# Event notifications from AWS private RDS to Lambda in VPC on column change

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, triggers, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I have a requirement that whenever a column "Status" changes value to "Completed" in a private RDS database table(Engine - MYSQL and not Aurora),lambda should be invoked.

I tried SQL trigger to call lambda on the column value change but call to AWS services is only supported in Aurora. RDS SNS event notifications do not appear to support column change.
Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.